# Ввести строку, вывести пословно на экран, но слова в обратном порядке.

Tags: c++

Необходимо ввести строку, вывести пословно на экран, но слова в обратном порядке.
Написал прогу, но не робит .____.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_reversed_words(char * str, const char * delim) {
if ( str = strtok(str, delim) ) {
print_reversed_words(NULL, delim);
printf("%s ", str);
}
}

typedef char string_t[256];
#define get_string(s) ( scanf("%255[^\n]%*c", (s)) == 1 )
#define DELIM " \t\n"

int main(void) {
string_t str;

while ( printf("\nString:   ") && get_string(str) && printf("Reversed: ") )
print_reversed_words(str, DELIM);

return 0;
}
```

Жалуется на

> 1>c:\users\алексей\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(2): warning C4627: #include <string.h>: пропущен при поиске использования предкомпилированного заголовка
>
> 1>c:\users\алексей\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(6): error C3861: strtok: идентификатор не найден

Голова не варит целый день, в чём проблема?

1. Компилятор MVS 2012

Comment: Верните на место `#include <stdafx.h>`.

Comment: Какой компилятор?

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey: исходя из логов, рискну предположить, что Visual Studio 2012

> c:\users\алексей\documents\visual studio 2012\[...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

во первых учтите что С++ != С

во вторых вы смешиваете два разных языка от того и проблемы, если хотите в современном С++ компиляторе использовать библиотеки С то уберите .h и укажите префикс "с" (вместо "string.h" пишите "сstring" и тоже самое с stdio)

в третьих как подключите старые библиотеки получите ошибки уже по вашему коду, которые надо будет исправлять